# Adding functions to an existing Objective-C class raises error

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocoa

I'm writing a C++ wrapper for the NSImage class and I'm having trouble with the additional functions that I wrote. Here's brief summary:

NSImageExtras.h

```
@interface NSImage (MyExtensions)
-(NSString*) myExtraFunction;
@end
```

NSImageExtras.mm

```
#import "NSImageExtras.h"

@implementation NSImage (MyExtensions)
-(NSString*) myExtraFunction
{
    return @"Hello World";
}
@end
```

NSImageWrapper.h

```
class NSImageWrapper
{
public:
    // nsImage is of type (NSImage*)
    NSImageWrapper(void* nsImage) {myImage = nsImage;}
    ~NSImageWrapper() {}

    CFStringRef myExtraFunction();

    // Cast this into (NSImage*)
    void* getNSImage() {return myImage;}

private:
    void* myImage;
};
```

NSImageWrapper.mm

```
#include "NSImageWrapper.h"
#import "NSImageExtras.h"

CFStringRef NSImageWrapper::myExtraFunction()
{
    return (CFStringRef) [(NSImage*) myImage myExtraFunction]; 
}
```

This compiles. But when I try to call `myExtraFunction` an error is raised because the function isn't found. If I change the `import "NSImageExtra.h"` into `import "NSImageExtra.m"` then it works, but I'd rather avoid adding .m files in my imports.

Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks ahead.

Comment: Have you tried handling NSImageExtra as an objective-C++ file? ( .mm )

Answer (score 0):

You can try to import NSImageExtras.h in NSImageWrapper.h instead of NSImageWrapper.mm. You need to include subclass headers in the header files.

Comment: I tried that, doesn't help :( This is a runtime error not a compilation error. (Note I edited my post: the .cpp file is actually .mm)

Comment: @OLL Did you rename NSImageExtras.m as NSImageExtras.mm?